# WebView as Tab Content

Tags: java, android, mobile, webview

I'm mucking around with tabs(using tutorials from the Dev Site) and I'm setting up tabs like so:

```
setupTab(new WebView(this), "Go to Google");
```

So that's working fine, when I click the 'Go to Google' tab, it shows a WebView, but what I want to know, is how do I make it load a specific site, at the moment it's loading a blank WebView.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep a reference to the webview and call `loadUrl`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: That's the same code? - anyway the error I get is: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method loadUrl(String) from the type WebView

Comment: @Andrew I doubt he means make a static call to WebView.loadUrl() (i don't even think there is a static method loadUrl() in WebView) ...rather call webView.loadUrl("google.co.uk"); where webView is the WebView defined by your tab activity.